# Write to texture memory on Nvidia device with OpenCL

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I'm failing to compile programs, using the `write_imagef()` functions on Nvidia implementations.
Working with a `Tesla K10.G2.8GB` using the driver version `367.35` on `python 2.7` with `PyopenCL 2016.1`,
I'm trying to compile the following program, which fails with a build error:

Host Code:

```
import pyopencl as cl

platform = cl.get_platforms()[0]
devs = platform.get_devices()
device1 = devs[1]
mf = cl.mem_flags
ctx = cl.Context([device1])
Queue1 = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

f = open('Minimal.cl', 'r')
fstr = "".join(f.readlines())
prg = cl.Program(ctx, fstr).build()
```

Kernel (Minimal.cl)

```
__kernel void test(image2d_t d_output){
    write_imagef(d_output,(int2)(1,1),(float4)(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f));
}
```

The error I get is:

```
pyopencl.cffi_cl.RuntimeError: clbuildprogram failed: BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE -
```

I checked, if my device has image support and that it supports reading and writing to
texture buffers in the specified format. I think, that the same case won't work for the 3d case,
because the extension `cl_khr_3d_image_writes` is not supported on any of our Nvidia devices,
but I don't understand the problem for the 2D case.

Comment: Problem seems not to be limited to this device. Occurs in every Nvidia implementation we are using.

Comment: When failing to build the program, call the PyopenCL equivalent of calling the OpenCL API clGetProgramBuildInfo with CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG to get human-readable description of what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image arguments must be declared as either `read_only` or `write_only` (or `read_write` with OpenCL 2.x), so your kernel definition should look like this:

```
__kernel void test(write_only image2d_t d_output){
    write_imagef(d_output,(int2)(1,1),(float4)(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f));
}
```

Comment: I just found that out myself. I just wonder, why this is mentioned nowhere in the standard documentation....